# Searching through a comma-separated field

Tags: mysql, sql-like

**Sample Table**

```
CREATE TABLE 
   `foo` (
        `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,     
        `keyword_ids` VARCHAR(128) ,     
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
   );
```

**Sample Data**

```
INSERT INTO 
    `foo`
SET
    `keyword_ids` = '14,10,5,19,12'
```

**Sample Query**

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `foo` 
WHERE 
    (`keyword_ids` LIKE '5,%%' 
    OR 
    `keyword_ids` LIKE '%%,5' 
    OR 
    `keyword_ids` = '5' 
    OR 
    `keyword_ids` LIKE '%%,5,%%')
```

As per my most recent question, this works just fine but **is there a way I can improve it?**

Comment: you could normalise it - that would be the first improvement i'd consider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    foo
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(5, keyword_ids)
```

Note, however, that this expression is still not sargable, that means an index on `keyword_ids` cannot improve this query.

You should normalize your model if you want this to be searchable fast.

Another option is to store comma-separated keywords (rather than `ids`) in the table and create a `FULLTEXT` index on them:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fx_foo_keyword ON (keywords)

SELECT  *
FROM    foo
WHERE   MATCH(keywords) AGAINST ('+keyword5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This, however, would only work on a `MyISAM` table.

Comment: Could you explain the "normalize your model" part?

Comment: @Sam: create a many-to-many link table `foo_keywords (foo_id, keyword_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.